# Sample code that takes a full resolution pciture

Tags: android

I've tried and tried and tried to find example code that takes a full E.g 5MP - not 800x480 preview sized picture but failed miserably.  Has anyone got any working code please?

Comment: Since posting, I've managed to find this source https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture which seems to work (I added in parameters.setPictureSize(2048,1536)in PictureDemo.java and it returned a jpeg with that size so it looks like a good basis to work with

Comment: You'd better use one of supported by a device resolutions. Supported resolutions can be get with `Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since posting, I've managed to find this source github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture which seems to work (I added in parameters.setPictureSize(2048,1536)in PictureDemo.java and it returned a jpeg with that size so it looks like a good basis to work with